# sticky header jagged movement

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently creating a website, and have encountered a problem, whenever I scroll with my sticky header, the page jumps to the bottom of the next element down, does anyone know why this could be?

I have tried changing the padding of basically all the elements on the page, including the banner, the heading, the text itself, and even the anchor elements, but nothing seems to fix my problem.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction()
};

var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu+Condensed);
body {
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  background-color: white;
}

.header {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}

.content {
  padding-top: : 16px;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky+.content {
  padding-top: 102px;
}

nav>div>a {
  padding: 6px 20px;
}

h3:hover {
  color: rgb(128, 128, 128)
}

h3 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.banner {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.image-cropper {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.header-text {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 25px;
}

.logo {
  margin-bottom: -80px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title> Nick Pemberton - About </title>
  <link rel="preload" href="../js/java.js" as="script">
  <link rel="preload" href="../css/main.css" as="style">
  <link rel="prerender" href="Gallery.html">
  <link rel="prerender" href="about.html">
  <link rel="prerender" href="HomePage.html">
  <link rel="preload" href="../photos/kilc/banner.jpg" as="image">
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="author" content="Nick Pemberton">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main.css">
  <!-- Link to main.css -->
</head>
<!-- /head -->

<body>
  <nav class="header" id="myHeader"><img src="../photos/test.png" class="logo">
    <div class="header-text">
      <a href="HomePage.html">
        <h3>Home
          <!-- Home -->
        </h3>
      </a>
      <a href="Gallery.html">
        <h3>Gallery
          <!-- Gallery -->
        </h3>
      </a>
      <a href="about.html">
        <h3>About</h3>
      </a>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- Nav Bar -->
  <content class="content">
    <img class="banner" src="../photos/kilc/banner.jpg"> A bunch of text is usually here, removed it since it is not relevant. A bunch of text is usually here, removed it since it is not relevant. A bunch of text is usually here, removed it since it is
    not relevant. A bunch of text is usually here, removed it since it is not relevant. A bunch of text is usually here, removed it since it is not relevant. A bunch of text is usually here, removed it since it is not relevant. A bunch of text is usually
    here, removed it since it is not relevant. A bunch of text is usually here, removed it since it is not relevant. A bunch of text is usually here, removed it since it is not relevant. A bunch of text is usually here, removed it since it is not relevant.
    A bunch of text is usually here, removed it since it is not relevant. A bunch of text is usually here, removed it since it is not relevant. A bunch of text is usually here, removed it since it is not relevant. A bunch of text is usually here, removed
    it since it is not relevant. A bunch of text is usually here, removed it since it is not relevant. A bunch of text is usually here, removed it since it is not relevant. A bunch of text is usually here, removed it since it is not relevant. A bunch
    of text is usually here, removed it since it is not relevant.
  </content>
  <!-- Content -->

  <script src="../js/java.js">
  </script>

</body>
<!-- body -->

</html>
<!-- html -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a custom tag `content` which is creating the issue since it will be by default an inline element and `padding-top` will not work as expected. Use a simple `div` or add `display:block` to that tag:

```js
var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
window.onscroll=myFunction;
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu+Condensed);
body {
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  background-color: white;
}

.header {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}

.content {
  padding-top: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
  font-size:32px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}

.sticky+.content {
  padding-top: 102px;
}

nav>div>a {
  padding: 6px 20px;
}

h3:hover {
  color: rgb(128, 128, 128)
}

h3 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.banner {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.image-cropper {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.header-text {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 25px;
}

.logo {
  margin-bottom: -80px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="header" id="myHeader">
  <div class="header-text">
    <a href="HomePage.html">
      <h3>Home
        <!-- Home -->
      </h3>
    </a>
    <a href="Gallery.html">
      <h3>Gallery
        <!-- Gallery -->
      </h3>
    </a>
    <a href="about.html">
      <h3>About</h3>
    </a>
  </div>
</nav>
<!-- Nav Bar -->
<div class="content">
   A bunch of text is usually here, removed it since it is not relevant. A bunch of text is usually here, removed it since it is not relevant. A bunch of text is usually here, removed it since it is
  not relevant. A bunch of text is usually here, removed it since it is not relevant. A bunch of text is usually here, removed it since it is not relevant. A bunch of text is usually here, removed it since it is not relevant.
  A bunch of text is usually here, removed it since it is not relevant. A bunch of text is usually here, removed it since it is not relevant. A bunch of text is usually here, removed it since it is
  not relevant. A bunch of text is usually here, removed it since it is not relevant. A bunch of text is usually here, removed it since it is not relevant. A bunch of text is usually here, removed it since it is not relevant.
  A bunch of text is usually here, removed it since it is not relevant. A bunch of text is usually here, removed it since it is not relevant. A bunch of text is usually here, removed it since it is
  not relevant. A bunch of text is usually here, removed it since it is not relevant. A bunch of text is usually here, removed it since it is not relevant. A bunch of text is usually here, removed it since it is not relevant.

</div>
<!-- Content -->
```

You can also simplify your code and consider `sticky` position instead of fixed:

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu+Condensed);
body {
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  background-color: white;
}

.header {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
}

.content {
  padding-top:16px;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
  font-size:32px;
}


.sticky+.content {
  padding-top: 102px;
}

nav>div>a {
  padding: 6px 20px;
}

h3:hover {
  color: rgb(128, 128, 128)
}

h3 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.banner {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.image-cropper {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.header-text {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 25px;
}

.logo {
  margin-bottom: -80px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="header" id="myHeader">
  <div class="header-text">
    <a href="HomePage.html">
      <h3>Home
        <!-- Home -->
      </h3>
    </a>
    <a href="Gallery.html">
      <h3>Gallery
        <!-- Gallery -->
      </h3>
    </a>
    <a href="about.html">
      <h3>About</h3>
    </a>
  </div>
</nav>
<!-- Nav Bar -->
<div class="content">
   A bunch of text is usually here, removed it since it is not relevant. A bunch of text is usually here, removed it since it is not relevant. A bunch of text is usually here, removed it since it is
  not relevant. A bunch of text is usually here, removed it since it is not relevant. A bunch of text is usually here, removed it since it is not relevant. A bunch of text is usually here, removed it since it is not relevant.
  A bunch of text is usually here, removed it since it is not relevant. A bunch of text is usually here, removed it since it is not relevant. A bunch of text is usually here, removed it since it is
  not relevant. A bunch of text is usually here, removed it since it is not relevant. A bunch of text is usually here, removed it since it is not relevant. A bunch of text is usually here, removed it since it is not relevant.
  A bunch of text is usually here, removed it since it is not relevant. A bunch of text is usually here, removed it since it is not relevant. A bunch of text is usually here, removed it since it is
  not relevant. A bunch of text is usually here, removed it since it is not relevant. A bunch of text is usually here, removed it since it is not relevant. A bunch of text is usually here, removed it since it is not relevant.

</div>
<!-- Content -->
```